# ion-textarea autoGrow scroll to top on input

Tags: ionic-framework, textarea, ionic5, autogrow

In my Ionic 5 app when an `ion-textarea` with `autoGrow="true"` becomes long in height, it always scrolls to top on input, when the user's input exceeds screen height. This exact issue was reported [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/19193) and the fix is said to be merged [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/pull/19776).

My Ionic version is 6.16.1 and I am facing this issue. The issue can be checked [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-autogrow-error)

Answer (score 1):

by checking the links you shared, there is this answer that seems to work on your stackblitz : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/pull/19776#issuecomment-549735550

In your html :

```
<ion-textarea auto-grow="true" (ionInput)="onTextInput($event)"> </ion-textarea>
```

In your .ts file :

```
onTextInput(event) { event.target.getInputElement().then((textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement) => { console.log(textArea.textLength + " : " + textArea.value); textArea.scroll({top: textArea.scrollHeight}); }); }
```

Comment: Yes, That is a workaround and I have tested it. I am looking for a fix for this issue in Ionic 5.